# Azure App Service File And Configuration Change Monitoring

Tags: azure, alert, monitoring, azure-appservice

As part of our production environment we have several App Services running inside of Azure. I would like to implement notifications to be sent to a specific email address upon file or configuration changes within those App Services. I have tried enabling Application Changes for the service but it does not appear to provide the capability to set up alerts on the changes,

[image]

I have also tried enabling App Service alerts but it does not appear that any of the test configuration changes that I have made were captured by the signal "Apply Web App Configuration".

[image]

The last thing that I tried was to enable Diagnostic Settings to capture AppServicePlatformLogs and AppServiceFileAuditLogs and stream them to an Event Hub, however, I cannot determine how to set up the email notification from the hub for the events.

[image]

I am hoping that there may be an easier way to set this up and was hoping that someone may have some pointers or resources that I can follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this under "Monitoring" -> "Alerts". A more detailed walkthrough can be found here https://perituza.com/blog/azure-app-service-monitoring-and-alerts/. The key was selecting "Activity Log - Administrative" as the Monitor Service in the Condition.